# how to list all places within 20 KM from point A

Tags: node.js, google-maps, express

my goal is simply list all the places within 20 KM from point A, Im using Google Maps API to help me with this

I use node.js/Express + mongoose for the backend part.

For example, If i live at Point A, and if I open up my phone, it would show all the list of places nearby my location which is Point A within 20 KM

How would I achieve this in the backend?

What are the condition should I pass to mongoose to find the list of places, or my approach is wrong?

```
Place.find({}, function(err, places) {
   res.json(places);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Place Search - Nearby Search request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

Here's a sample Nearby Search request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

Include *rankby* parameter to specifiy the order in which results are listed. Possible values are **prominence, distance and location**.

Here's a related SO ticket: 
[Google Nearby places search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818323/google-nearby-places-search)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Places API Web services.

You have 2 aptions to search 1) Nearby search returns complete information of each place but it returns up to 20 results on each query and if more places available, it returns a "next page" token.

```
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+lat+","+long+"&radius=" +radius+"&types=" + types + "&key=<PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>";
```

lat and long are your center coordinates. radius is measured in meters and is a value up to 50000. types is the type of Place you are searching according to this listing: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types . Example: "atm"

2) Radar search that returns a reduced set of information of each place but it returns up to 200 on each query

```
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location="+lat+","+long+"&radius=" +radius+"&types=" + types + "&key=<PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>";
```

lat and long are your center coordinates. radius is measured in meters and is a value up to 50000. types is the type of Place you are searching according to this listing: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types . Example: "atm"

You have more options to search, keyword & name appart from type. **Keep in mind that you must specify at least one of them.**

You can have your results on xml or json format.

Full definition of nearby and radar search is here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search