# Alternative to Google Maps API Radar Search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With Radar search being taken off, are there any other alternatives that Google has proposed (or any other source, if not Google) to get information on all businesses in a given location.

In the end I am interested in obtaining a list of all business in a city, say Delhi, legally (I guess web scraping Google Maps would be illegal).

Google Maps Radar Search - https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html:

"[Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) can work as an alternative for Radar Search, when used with rankby=distance and without keyword or name."

If you are searching for a specific business type, you could specify a "type" as a parameter with Nearby Search from [this list](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types)

Comment: I'm confused, in the API reference it says "If rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is specified, then one or more of keyword, name, or type is required."? [API reference](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)

Answer (score 1):

No alternative for Radar Search is available. Which returned a maximum of 200 results sorted by distance in a particular radius. Don't know why Google discontinued it, it was such a useful api for the developers.

You'll have to use Nearby search only as an alternative which is limited to return max of 60 results. No other way.